# Transmission 3.0 update (Ubuntu 16.04) - using wrong settings folder

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, transmission-daemon

System just updated to Transmission 3.0.  Things stopped working; initially RPC access. After trying lots of things, it wouldn't connect. So I've followed these instructions to 'start again' : https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/install-transmission-web-interface-on-ubuntu-1204/  (stoping before Step 7)

I turned on logging to debug level and got this

```
Couldn't read "/home/debian-transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json": No such file o
r directory (utils.c:263
```

I've looked back at the steps and none of them mention this */home/debian-transmission/* directory.  Is it a default that is set somewhere?  Could it be a Link that's gone wrong?  Or something that has to be done differently for 3.0?  Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.